# Using the same Compass sprite in different stylesheets

Tags: sprite, compass-sass, css-sprites

I'm using Compass to generate CSS sprites.

I found a way to define a sprite once and use it across different .scss files, but I'm not sure this is the right solution.

The best way I could find until now is:

- create a `_variables.scss` partial file
- define the sprite inside the `_variables.scss` partial file
- import the `_variables.scss` partial in every .scss file

**Example**

_variables.scss file:

```
$siteSprite-spacing: 20px; 
@import "siteSprite/*.png";
```

firstPage.scss file:

```
@import "../variables.scss";

.close {
    @include siteSprite-sprite(close, true);
}
```

secondPage.scss file:

```
@import "../variables.scss";

.viewMore {
    @include siteSprite-sprite(arrow, true);
}
```

**And this works, but...**

The problem is that every time that Compass compiles the scss files (firstPage.scss, secondPage.scss) it reads the _variables.scss partial and then reads all the images, trying to generate the sprite each time.

The result is that the *compile* process ends up in this:

```
   create generated_images/siteSprite-s526a535d08.png
unchanged generated_images/siteSprite-s526a535d08.png
   create css/firstPage.css 
unchanged generated_images/siteSprite-s526a535d08.png
   create css/secondPage.css
unchanged generated_images/siteSprite-s526a535d08.png
   create css/thirdPage.css
unchanged generated_images/siteSprite-s526a535d08.png
```

And this is extremely slow, because I have many pages and many files inside the siteSprite image folder.

How can I avoid this problem?

Comment: What's the reason for doing a stylesheet for each page? Could you perhaps create a global stylesheet that references the sprites? If you're separating out the styles for each page, why not separate the sprites for that page?

Comment: @verlok,  the unchanged line should be very quick. I ran a test with my own sprite sheet and each unchanged line was pretty much instant for me.  The create line, yes that will be painfully slow, especially if you have a large sprite.

Comment: Only `create` means compass is generating the sprite. `unchanged` should be much quicker.

Answer (score 2):

I will explain how I use compass sprites and hopefully this will be helpful to you too.
I usually create a _base.scss partial file, in which I put all the generic @import's and @include's plus any generic css code for my project. In the _base.scss I also add the following sprites-specific code (assuming that the folder, where I keep my icons, is called "icon" and that my icons have a .png extension):

```
@import "compass/utilities/sprites";
@import "icon/*.png";
@include all-icon-sprites;
```

This _base.scss is the first file that I import in any *.css.scss file (the equivalent of your "firstPage.scss" and "firstPage.scss") of my project.

Now, to use any of these sprites inside a div, I just do this:

```
#my_id (or .my_class) {
    @extend .icon-myicon;
}
```

where "myicon" is the name of one .png file inside the "icon" folder.

This [compass tutorial](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/spriting/) is actually very helpful, so you may want to have a look.

If you are worried that some files may end up being imported more than once, you can try using the plugin [compass-import-once](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/tree/master/import-once).